# Draw a line in mfc with help of toolbar

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to make a paint application in MFC using visul basic c++ 6.0 i have already created a window using Create function and also have created a toolbar with a tool line but i am stuck on how to code for the line because the function i know goes like d.lineTo(x,y) and d.Moveto(x2,y2) but it comes under the line function how do i use OnLButtonDown to Trap the co-ordiantes or is there any other way i can draw a line ..? any help will be useful

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the MFC Scribble tutorial : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716527%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

It will get you started on how to handling mouse click and mouse move and drawing.

M.

Comment: i am planning to have some colors in the toolbox which would make it similar to paint but i am unable to find any help can u help ..?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're going to have to override several member functions to do this.  I've outlined an approach below.  My example below deals with a single line-drawing operation (from mouse down, to mouse up).  An exercise for you, is to make it so that once you've done one, you can then do another at a different place.  It's easy, btw!

```
CWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT _flags, CPoint _pt);
CWnd::OnLButtonUp(UINT _flags, CPoint _pt);
CWnd::OnMouseMove(UINT _flags, CPoint _pt);
CWnd::OnPaint()
```

Apologies if some of these function signatures are wrong!  Add some members to your window class:

```
// at the top of your file
#include <vector>

// in your class
typedef std::vector<POINT> PointVector;
PointVector m_Points;


CYourWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT _flags, CPoint _pt);
{
    // NOTE: For more than one set of drawing, this will be different!
    m_Points.clear();
    m_Points.push_back(POINT(_pt.x, _pt.y));
}

CYourWnd::OnMouseMove(UINT _flags, CPoint _pt);
{
    if(_flags & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
        const POINT& last(m_Points.back());
        if(_pt.x != last.x || _pt.y != last.y)
        {
            m_Points.push_back(POINT(_pt.x, _pt.y));
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

CYourWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rcClient; GetClientRect(&rc);
    FillSolidRect(&rcClient, RGB(255, 255, 255));

    if(m_Points.size())
    {
        dc.MoveTo(m_Points[0].x, m_Points[0].y);
        for(PointsVector::size_type p(1);
            p < m_Points.size();
            ++p)
           dc.LineTo(m_Points[p].x, m_Points[p].y);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is crude and gives you a single drawing operation.  Once you click the left button down again, it erases what you've done.  So, once you have this working:

1. Make it so you can draw an unlimited amount of lines.  You could accomplish this in several ways such as an additional container (to store vectors), or even drawing-operation classes that you can store in a single vector and then execute.
2. This solution may well flicker.  How might you stop this?  Perhaps `OnEraseBkgnd` holds the clue...
3. How about more colours?

All signs point towards creating some drawing-classes that encapsulate this for you, but I hope this has got you started.