# How to create a paint application with toolbars having color and shapes in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, paint

I have been trying to create a paint application in visual c++ but all i know is that functions such as OnLButtonDown and OnMouseMove but i want to have similar functionality as of paint where user can draw a rectangle or a circle and even color it to , i found out the scribble tutorial in msdn but was not that helpful

Comment: You seem to be basically asking how to write the program. The answer to such a question cannot be provided in this format. Scribble is a great place to start. Learn the example well, buy some good books, and come back here if you get stuck and have a specific question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw a line in mfc with help of toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680549/draw-a-line-in-mfc-with-help-of-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

I gave you an example and some exercises to do the last time you asked this and you ignored.

See again:

[Draw a line in mfc with help of toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680549/draw-a-line-in-mfc-with-help-of-toolbar/4691275#4691275)